Connection Manager in SSIS task: Keyword not supported: 'ProviderName'
When I'm creating an ADO.NET connection from connection managers of the solution explorer in VS2022, it's all fine. But when I wanna create a connection in the data profiling task of SSIS toolbox, I get this error:

TITLE: Connection Manager Test connection failed because of an error
in initializing provider. Keyword not supported: 'ProviderName'.

As you can see in the picture (right hand side) I have managed to create this same exact connection in connection managers with similar parameters, however with .Net Providers\Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider As Provider name and if I choose .Net Providers\SqlClient Data Provider I get the above error again. The problem is in the connection manager of SSIS task, I cant change the provider as it's greyed out. Can you help me fix this issue?



Why not use OLEDB/ODBC?

@ThomA, It has only the ADO.NET option.

Have you not installed the latest OLEDB driver?

@ThomA I believe it is installed when installing sql server. So, I have Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (ver 18.7.4.0) in my app list.

Installing SQL Server does not install the latest OLEDB driver, but sounds like you do have it installed. I suggest using that, if I am honest.

My first connection in the connection manager is with OLE DB, and it works fine, but the only option in profiling task editor is ADO.NET without the possibility of changing the provider.

According to this question ADO does not support Application Name as a parameter.

As noted in the SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022 Version 1.5 bug fix, this issue was identified as a bug and resolved after updating Visual Studio. I'll leave this question up in case anyone else encounters the same problem.

SQLClient Data Provider for ADO.Net test connection error resolved. (Upgrade VS version to VS2022 17.12 preview 2)


Thanks to Pankaj who said:

To resolve this error, you have two options
Option#1: Upgrade Visual Studio to VS2022 17.12 Preview 2 or higher:

This approach ensures compatibility between your development environment and the latest version of SSIS.
It’s a reliable solution if you’re comfortable with using a preview version of Visual Studio or wait for the public release.

Option#2: Downgrade SSIS to Version 1.3.2:

This option involves reverting to an older version of SSIS that is known to work with older Visual Studio versions.
However, downgrading might introduce compatibility issues with other components or features in your project.


IT WORKED FOR ME

Have you tried setting the connection string without the provider name, it worked for me

IDK how to that in visual studio tbh, just started working with it.
